# Nested configuration by yaml - spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Below is my yaml configuration.

```
configuration:
  internalUser:
    add:
      city:            
        path: path
        name: cityName

      country:            
        path: path
        name: countryName
                  
    replace:
      city:                       
        path: path
        name: cityName
    remove:
      city:                       
        path: path
        name: cityName
  externalUser:
    add:
      city:            
        path: path
        name: cityName

      country:            
        path: path
        name: countryName
                  
    replace:
      city:                       
        path: path
        name: cityName
    remove:
      city:                       
        path: path
        name: cityName
```

Configuration class look like:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "configuration")
public class Configuration {

    private Map<String, Map<String,Map<String>,Address>>> internalUser = new HashMap<>();
     //setter and getter
}

Public class Address{
       private String path;
       private String name;
       //setter and getter
    }
```

While loading the application it is failing and not able to cast the object.

Is there anything is wrong with my configuration? Or can We use the **nested configuration** for this configuration?
Please help me in the configuration.

Comment: Post your error code. And you have a typo in the Map generic type `Map<String>,Address`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one too many maps. You only need two maps.

First map keys: `add, replace, remove`

Second map keys: `city`

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "configuration")
public class Configuration {

    private Map<String, Map<String, Address>>> internalUser;
    private Map<String, Map<String, Address>>> externalUser;
     //setter and getter
}
```